# How do I write system-independent code when there are paths involved?

Tags: c++, path, linker, makefile

Say I am creating a project that uses a certain library and I have to provide the path for that library while linking. In the command line or makefile I might have:

```
g++ ... -L/path/to/mylibrary
```

I'm also going to send this project to someone else who wants to use it. The path on their system might not necessarily be the same as mine. They could be using a different file path all together.

How do I make sure that the path to the library works for both my computer and the recipient of my project?

Comment: Make sure you have `LIBDIR = /path/to/mylibrary` as a definition in the makefile, and you use `-L${LIBDIR}` in the linkage rules in the makefile.  Similarly, you should be using a macro for everything that might need to change (so you need a macro for your C++ compiler name, for example — usually CXX).  If need be, your colleague can then either edit the macro definition in the makefile or run `make LIBDIR=/other/path/to/library`.

Comment: similarly you should be using ${CXX} not g++ directly.  Also note that make has quite a few implicit rules and you should be be using them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the role of a build system or build configuration tool. There are many of those around. The main one is probably [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) as it has a very extensive feature set, cross-platform, and widely adopted. There are others like [Boost.Jam](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/jam.html), [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/), and others.

The way that these tools will be used is that they have automated scripts for looking into the file-system and finding the headers or libraries that you need, i.e., the dependencies required to compile your code. They can also be used to do all sorts of other fancy things, like checking what features the OS supports and reconfiguring the build as a consequence of that. But the point is, you don't hard-code any file-paths into the build configuration, everything is either relative to your source folder or it is found automatically by the build script.

Here is an example CMake file for a project that uses Boost:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (ExampleWithBoost)

find_package(Boost 1.46 COMPONENTS thread program_options filesystem REQUIRED)

# Add the boost directory to the include paths:
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
# Add the boost library directory to the link paths:
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# Add an executable target (for compilation):
add_executable(example_with_boost example_with_boost.cpp)
# Add boost libraries to the linking on the target:
target_link_libraries(example_with_boost ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The `find_package` cmake function is simply a special script (specialized for Boost, and installed with CMake) that finds the latest version of boost (with some minimal version) installed on the system, and it does so based on the file-name patterns that the library uses. You can also write your own equivalents of `find_package`, or even your own package finders, using the functions that CMake provides for searching the file system for certain file-name patterns (e.g., regular expressions).

As you see, the build configuration file above only refer directly to your source files, like "example_with_boost.cpp", and it's only relative to the source folder. If you do things right, the configuration scripts will work on virtually any system and any OS that CMake supports (and that the libraries you depend on support). This is how most major cross-platform projects work, and when you understand how to work with these systems, it's very powerful and very easy to use (in general, far easier to use and trouble-free than build configurations that you do by point-and-click within IDE menus like in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0):

You can use premake that generates cross platform makefiles: Visual Studio, Gcc and others

http://industriousone.com/what-premake

CMake is another alternative

http://www.cmake.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a single universal way of doing this, but people often provide different config files and let the main Makefile detect which one to include: `linux.make`, `darwin.make`, `cygwin.make` etc.

there are also various tools like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) that allow to automate this, but all in all it's just scripting that hides the system-dependency from the developer.

Comment: This is insufficient since note all darwin systems or linux systems look the same. Also it is missing all the bsds.

Comment: g(nu)make is also available for other systems and is commonly used for ports. Only stuff that goes into BSD basesystem must use BSD make afaik